# How do I use boost's set_exception_handler?

Tags: c++, boost

I want to set a global exception handler in C++. With a hook, any exceptions (of a specified type) thrown, would be caught by the handler. With this, I could do a little pretty printing before the exception kills the program, or maybe I could write everything to a log file.

boost seems to have an exception handler hook. [This](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/log/doc/html/log/detailed/utilities.html#log.detailed.utilities.exception_handlers) seemed extremely promising, but the code provided didn't work as I thought it should. Am I missing something?

```
struct my_handler
{
    typedef void result_type;

    void operator() (std::runtime_error const& e) const
    {
        std::cout << "std::runtime_error: " << e.what() << std::endl;
    }
    void operator() (std::logic_error const& e) const
    {
        std::cout << "std::logic_error: " << e.what() << std::endl;
        throw;
    }
};

void init_exception_handler()
{
    // Setup a global exception handler that will call my_handler::operator()
    // for the specified exception types
    logging::core::get()->set_exception_handler(logging::make_exception_handler<
        std::runtime_error,
        std::logic_error
    >(my_handler()));
}

// The above is all code from the boost doc example. Untouched.
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
     init_exception_handler();
     // I can throw now right...?
     throw std::runtime_error("This should be suppressed!");
     return 0;
}
```

In this code, the runtime_error I throw is not suppressed even though I thought I had setup the exception handler.

Comment: An exception can only be caught in a `catch` clause. To catch exceptions globally, you have to have a global `try ... catch` statement, that is, one that wraps `main`. The boost exception handler works only in boost calls, and only because every catch clause in boost calls it. If you want it to work in your function, you have to make sure (1) it's wrapped in try/catch and (2) you call the handler from within its catch clause.

Comment: If you want to handle *uncaught* exceptions, you should use `set_terminate`.